# JSON stringify with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem with an ajax call returns a json.
I construct the json file in this way:

```
$hotel_array2 = array();
.....
$hotel_array2['name'] = str_replace('\'', '', $hotel->HotelDetails->Name);
....
array_push($arr_return['hotel'], $hotel_array2);

echo(json_encode($arr_return));
```

the ajax call is  this:

```
$.ajax({   
                url: site_url_veturis, 
                type: "GET", 
                async: true,
                data: window.location.search, 
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 50000,
                success: function(data) {

                },
                error: function(data) {

                }
            })
```

The strange problem is if I see with firebug the response in tab response the json is:

```
{"hotel":[{"id":"17911","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Thistle Liverpool
 City Centre, Atlantic Tower","rating":4,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name"
:"","area_code":"","address":"CHAPEL STREET ","description":"HOTEL: This hotel and was built in 1975
. Was renovated in 1999, has 12 floors, 225 rooms, 217 double rooms and 2 suites. Clients have available
 a lobby with a reception and lifts. \n\nSITUATION: This urban hotel, is located in a main street. It
 is in a tourist area. 500 metres away, clients can find restaurants, bars and nightclubs. 1 kilometre
 away, there are shops. \n\nROOM: The comfortable, en-suite rooms. They have a hairdryer, a direct line
 telephone, satellite or cable television, a radio, a fridge, a minibar, fitted carpet, a safe-deposit
 box and a central heating system. \n\nMEALS: Regarding gastronomy, the establishment has a buffet breakfast
 and \u00e0 la carte or set-menu lunch and dinner. Dietary restrictions can be accomodated and special
 dishes made. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: Accepted payment methods are American Express, Visa, Eurocard, Mastercard
 and Diners Club.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/17\/17911_15.jpg","latitudine":"53
.4076538","longitudine":"-2.9936891","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency"
:"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"0.16","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"20770","provider_name"
:"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Campanile Liverpool","rating":2,"nation":"97","city"
:"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":"","address":"CHALONER STREET - QUEENS
 DOCK ","description":"HOTEL: This tourist hotel. Was built in 1990, has 100 rooms and 2 floors. Customers
 have available a reception, a cosy bar, a restaurant, a conference room, internet, a laundry service
 and a car park. \n\nSITUATION: It is situated near the historic harbour Albert Docks. This inviting
 hotel, is a few minutes walk from the city centre, where you can find shops, leisure areas, monuments
 and tourist points of interest. \n\nROOM: The rooms are cosy and they have an ensuite bathroom with
 hairdryer. They have a direct line telephone, a radio and a central heating system. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS
: The establishment accepts American Express, Visa and Mastercard.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis
.com\/photos\/20\/20770_4.jpg","latitudine":"53.3949623","longitudine":"-2.9839790","max_age_infant"
:"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"1.57","markup_agency"
:"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"21903","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name"
:"Britannia Adelphi","rating":3,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name"
:"","area_code":"","address":"RANELAGH PLACE , L3 5UL","description":"HOTEL: Urban and was built in 1914
. It has 6 floors, 402 rooms, 27 single rooms, 373 double rooms and 2 suites. In the establishment entrance
 guests are offered a lobby with elevators, a reception with a safe deposit box, a currency exchange
, a car park and a garage. Customers have at their disposal a pub, a bar, a restaurant with highchairs
 and internet. Some services offered by the establishment are room service and a laundry service. \n
\nSITUATION: This urban hotel, is situated in the city centre of Liverpool. 3 minutes away, guests can
 find the Lime Street Station. \n\nROOM: The rooms comfortable, en-suite with hairdryer. They have a
 direct line telephone, satellite or cable TV, a radio, internet, fitted carpet, a central heating system
 and a safe-deposit box. \n\nFACILITIES: Customers have at their disposal a swimming pool, a bar, parasols
, a jacuzzi, a sauna, a solarium, a Turkish bath and a massage service. Clients can enjoy activities
 such as squash and do aerobics. The establishment also has a gym. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: Accepted payment
 methods are American Express, Visa, Eurocard, Mastercard, Diners Club and EC. \n\nOTHERS: Regarding
 gastronomy, clients can enjoy all meals in buffet form, \u00e0 la carte or set-menu lunch and a set-menu
 dinner.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/hotel-Britannia-Adelphi-F21903_1.jpg","latitudine":"53
.4051056","longitudine":"-2.9796340","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency"
:"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"0.87","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"40472","provider_name"
:"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Jurys Inn Liverpool","rating":3,"nation":"97","city"
:"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":"","address":"Keel Wharf 31","description"
:"HOTEL: This hotel was built in 2008 air-conditioned and it has 310 large, comfortable rooms, with private
 bathroom. Clients have available a lobby with a reception, a safe, a currency exchange, a lift, a bar
, a restaurant, conference facilities and a car park at an additional cost. \n\nSITUATION: This urban
 hotel, is located close to the river. It is in Liverpool. It is in front of the new stadium and the
 Congress Centre. It is located close to the historic dock Albert Docks. It is in the city centre. 200
 metres from the establishment, you can find the train station Lime Street. It is 14 kilometres away
 from John Lennon Airport. It is situated 60 kilometres away from Manchester Airport. 90 kilometres from
 the establishment, guests will find Blackpool Airport. \n\nROOM: The rooms are large, bright and modern
. They have a bathroom, an air-conditioning system, internet, a radio, a television, a coffee maker,
 a kettle, an individual air-conditioning system and individual heating. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: Customers
 can pay with credit cards, debit cards, American Express, Diners Club, Mastercard and Visa. \n\nOTHERS
: Regarding gastronomy, clients have English or continental breakfast and an \u00e0 la carte or set-menu
 dinner. The establishment also offers meal service in the bar.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com
\/photos\/40\/40472_1.jpg","latitudine":"53.3960730","longitudine":"-2.9879199","max_age_infant":"0"
,"max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"1.39","markup_agency"
:"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"23014","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name"
:"Radisson Blu Liverpool","rating":4,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name"
:"","area_code":"","address":"OLD HALL STREET 107","description":"HOTEL: This urban is ideal for relaxing
 hotel. Was opened in 2004, has 194 rooms, 9 floors, 189 double rooms and 5 suites. In the establishment
 entrance guests are offered a large hall with an elevator, a reception with a safe deposit box, a currency
 exchange and a cloakroom. Clients have available a caf\u00e9, a conference room, a cocktail bar, an
 air-conditioned \u00e0 la carte restaurant and internet. Some of the services on offer are room service
 and a laundry service. \n\nSITUATION: It is located in the city centre of Liverpool. It is in front
 of the Mersey River. 500 metres away from the establishment, guests will find shops and leisure areas
. 100 metres away there is a public transport stop. It is situated 11.5 kilometres away from the airport
. \n\nROOM: The rooms comfortable, en-suite with hairdryer. They have a direct line telephone, satellite
 TV, a radio, internet, a safe available at an additional cost, a minibar and a central heating system
. \n\nFACILITIES: Customers have at their disposal a covered pool, a gym, a sauna, a jacuzzi, a Turkish
 bath, a massage service and a beauty treatment service. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: The establishment accepts
 American Express, Visa, Mastercard and Diners Club. \n\nOTHERS: Regarding gastronomy, clients have breakfast
 in a buffet form and a set-menu lunch and dinner.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/23
\/23014_2.jpg","latitudine":"53.4103012","longitudine":"-2.9960999","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child"
:"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"0.37","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"
},{"id":"68152","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Novotel Liverpool"
,"rating":4,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":""
,"address":"40 HANOVER STREET ","description":"HOTEL: This hoterestauranter, was opened in 2009, has
 209 rooms, a designer, a bar and a car park with a security system. This air-conditioned conference
, hotel, has a reception, a safe, a currency exchange, a lift, conference facilities, internet, room
 service and a laundry service. \n\nSITUATION: This urban hotel, is located in Paradise Street and Hanover
 Street. It is in the centre of Liverpool. Close to the establishment clients can find Matthew Street
 and Cavern club. It is close to the Lime Street Station. It is 2 minutes away from the Liverpool One
 Shopping Centre, where you can find restaurants, bars and shops. It is 10 kilometres away from John
 Lennon Airport. \n\nROOM: The rooms are modern and comfortable, have ensuite bathrooms with bath or
 shower, a sofa-bed, a large workspace, an LCD television, films available at an additional cost, internet
, a hairdryer, an ironing set, computer safe, a minibar, a coffee maker, a kettle, an individual air-conditioning
 system and a central heating system. \n\nFACILITIES: Guests have at their disposal a sauna, hydromassage
, tanning salon, a gym and a covered heated swimming pool. Some services for an additional fee. \n\nOTHERS
: Regarding gastronomy, the establishment offers a buffet breakfast. It has the Elements <with_breakfast_lunch_dinner_service
 Id=\"N-2877451-2765654\">with A Breakfast, Lunch And Dinner Service<\/with_breakfast_lunch_dinner_service
> Restaurant. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: Accepted payment methods are credit cards, American Express, Diners
 Club, Mastercard, Visa and debit cards.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/68\/68152_8
.jpg","latitudine":"53.4029200","longitudine":"-2.9844403","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12"
,"status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"0.77","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"
},{"id":"67575","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Hope Street Hotel"
,"rating":4,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":""
,"address":"40 HOPE STREET ","description":"HOTEL:\nBuilt around 1860 in the style of a Venetian palazo
 - a fashionable look of the day. Reinvented and renovated in 2003 into 48 simple, stylish, contemporary
 and comfortable rooms with a restaurant. Privately owned and independently run with an emphasis on friendliness
, good food and thoughtful service.\n\nSITUACI\u00d3N:\nSitting pretty between two magnificent cathedrals
, surrounded by two famous theatres, two legendary pubs, one treasured concert hall, and an abundance
 and variety of restaurants. Further afield they are a five minute walk into town and a 20 min drive
 to Liverpool John Lennon Airport.\n\nHABITACI\u00d3N:\n48 individually designed rooms, solid wood floors
 warmed by under floor heating and king sized beds draped in Egyptian cotton. Rain dance showerheads
 the size of dinner plates and Vola fittings complement timeless bathrooms that also include huge soft
 towels, mist free mirrors and REN products. Wall mounted LCD wide screen TVs, DVD and CD players and
 Arne Jacobsen telephones, along with complimentary broadband access in every room.\n\nCOMO LLEGAR:\nBy
 Car: From Liverpool John Lennon Airport - Depart. At the roundabout, take the first exit. At the roundabout
, take the first exit onto Speke Hall Avenue. At the roundabout, take the second exit onto Speke Hall
 Avenue. Turn left onto Speke Road A561. the roundabout, take the first exit onto Speke Road A561. Continue
 onto A561. Turn left onto Dingle Lane A561. Turn right onto Park Road A561. Continue onto A561. Bear
 right onto Great George Street A5038. Bear right onto Berry Street A5038. Turn right onto Leece Street
 A5039. Continue onto A5039. Turn right onto Pilgrim Street. Turn left onto Back Hope Place. Arrive.
\n\nMETODOS DE PAGO:\nVisa, American Express, MasterCard, Maestro and cash are accepted as methods of
 payment.\n\nOTRAS:\nThe London Carriage Works: modern international food, complemented by the use of
 local, organic and fresh seasonal produce. One of Liverpools leading restaurants, enjoying rave reviews
 and critical acclaim. It was voted one of the top ten restaurants outside London in the 2005 Hardens
 Guide and achieved Liverpools highest score for cooking in The Good Food Guide 2006. Most recently it
 won Taste of Englands Northwest 2008.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/67\/67575_1.jpg"
,"latitudine":"53.4008340","longitudine":"-2.9710220","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status"
:"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"1.60","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"}],"room"
:[],"amenities":[]}
```

If in firebug I click on response but HTML json is:

```
{"hotel":[{"id":"17911","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Thistle Liverpool City Centre, Atlantic Tower","rating":4,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":"","address":"CHAPEL STREET ","description":"HOTEL: This hotel and was built in 1975. Was renovated in 1999, has 12 floors, 225 rooms, 217 double rooms and 2 suites. Clients have available a lobby with a reception and lifts. \n\nSITUATION: This urban hotel, is located in a main street. It is in a tourist area. 500 metres away, clients can find restaurants, bars and nightclubs. 1 kilometre away, there are shops. \n\nROOM: The comfortable, en-suite rooms. They have a hairdryer, a direct line telephone, satellite or cable television, a radio, a fridge, a minibar, fitted carpet, a safe-deposit box and a central heating system. \n\nMEALS: Regarding gastronomy, the establishment has a buffet breakfast and \u00e0 la carte or set-menu lunch and dinner. Dietary restrictions can be accomodated and special dishes made. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: Accepted payment methods are American Express, Visa, Eurocard, Mastercard and Diners Club.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/17\/17911_15.jpg","latitudine":"53.4076538","longitudine":"-2.9936891","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"0.16","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"20770","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Campanile Liverpool","rating":2,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":"","address":"CHALONER STREET - QUEENS DOCK ","description":"HOTEL: This tourist hotel. Was built in 1990, has 100 rooms and 2 floors. Customers have available a reception, a cosy bar, a restaurant, a conference room, internet, a laundry service and a car park. \n\nSITUATION: It is situated near the historic harbour Albert Docks. This inviting hotel, is a few minutes walk from the city centre, where you can find shops, leisure areas, monuments and tourist points of interest. \n\nROOM: The rooms are cosy and they have an ensuite bathroom with hairdryer. They have a direct line telephone, a radio and a central heating system. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: The establishment accepts American Express, Visa and Mastercard.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/20\/20770_4.jpg","latitudine":"53.3949623","longitudine":"-2.9839790","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"1.57","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"21903","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Britannia Adelphi","rating":3,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":"","address":"RANELAGH PLACE , L3 5UL","description":"HOTEL: Urban and was built in 1914. It has 6 floors, 402 rooms, 27 single rooms, 373 double rooms and 2 suites. In the establishment entrance guests are offered a lobby with elevators, a reception with a safe deposit box, a currency exchange, a car park and a garage. Customers have at their disposal a pub, a bar, a restaurant with highchairs and internet. Some services offered by the establishment are room service and a laundry service. \n\nSITUATION: This urban hotel, is situated in the city centre of Liverpool. 3 minutes away, guests can find the Lime Street Station. \n\nROOM: The rooms comfortable, en-suite with hairdryer. They have a direct line telephone, satellite or cable TV, a radio, internet, fitted carpet, a central heating system and a safe-deposit box. \n\nFACILITIES: Customers have at their disposal a swimming pool, a bar, parasols, a jacuzzi, a sauna, a solarium, a Turkish bath and a massage service. Clients can enjoy activities such as squash and do aerobics. The establishment also has a gym. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: Accepted payment methods are American Express, Visa, Eurocard, Mastercard, Diners Club and EC. \n\nOTHERS: Regarding gastronomy, clients can enjoy all meals in buffet form, \u00e0 la carte or set-menu lunch and a set-menu dinner.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/hotel-Britannia-Adelphi-F21903_1.jpg","latitudine":"53.4051056","longitudine":"-2.9796340","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"0.87","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"40472","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Jurys Inn Liverpool","rating":3,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":"","address":"Keel Wharf 31","description":"HOTEL: This hotel was built in 2008 air-conditioned and it has 310 large, comfortable rooms, with private bathroom. Clients have available a lobby with a reception, a safe, a currency exchange, a lift, a bar, a restaurant, conference facilities and a car park at an additional cost. \n\nSITUATION: This urban hotel, is located close to the river. It is in Liverpool. It is in front of the new stadium and the Congress Centre. It is located close to the historic dock Albert Docks. It is in the city centre. 200 metres from the establishment, you can find the train station Lime Street. It is 14 kilometres away from John Lennon Airport. It is situated 60 kilometres away from Manchester Airport. 90 kilometres from the establishment, guests will find Blackpool Airport. \n\nROOM: The rooms are large, bright and modern. They have a bathroom, an air-conditioning system, internet, a radio, a television, a coffee maker, a kettle, an individual air-conditioning system and individual heating. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: Customers can pay with credit cards, debit cards, American Express, Diners Club, Mastercard and Visa. \n\nOTHERS: Regarding gastronomy, clients have English or continental breakfast and an \u00e0 la carte or set-menu dinner. The establishment also offers meal service in the bar.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/40\/40472_1.jpg","latitudine":"53.3960730","longitudine":"-2.9879199","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"1.39","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"23014","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Radisson Blu Liverpool","rating":4,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":"","address":"OLD HALL STREET 107","description":"HOTEL: This urban is ideal for relaxing hotel. Was opened in 2004, has 194 rooms, 9 floors, 189 double rooms and 5 suites. In the establishment entrance guests are offered a large hall with an elevator, a reception with a safe deposit box, a currency exchange and a cloakroom. Clients have available a caf\u00e9, a conference room, a cocktail bar, an air-conditioned \u00e0 la carte restaurant and internet. Some of the services on offer are room service and a laundry service. \n\nSITUATION: It is located in the city centre of Liverpool. It is in front of the Mersey River. 500 metres away from the establishment, guests will find shops and leisure areas. 100 metres away there is a public transport stop. It is situated 11.5 kilometres away from the airport. \n\nROOM: The rooms comfortable, en-suite with hairdryer. They have a direct line telephone, satellite TV, a radio, internet, a safe available at an additional cost, a minibar and a central heating system. \n\nFACILITIES: Customers have at their disposal a covered pool, a gym, a sauna, a jacuzzi, a Turkish bath, a massage service and a beauty treatment service. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: The establishment accepts American Express, Visa, Mastercard and Diners Club. \n\nOTHERS: Regarding gastronomy, clients have breakfast in a buffet form and a set-menu lunch and dinner.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/23\/23014_2.jpg","latitudine":"53.4103012","longitudine":"-2.9960999","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"0.37","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"68152","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Novotel Liverpool","rating":4,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":"","address":"40 HANOVER STREET ","description":"HOTEL: This hoterestauranter, was opened in 2009, has 209 rooms, a designer, a bar and a car park with a security system. This air-conditioned conference, hotel, has a reception, a safe, a currency exchange, a lift, conference facilities, internet, room service and a laundry service. \n\nSITUATION: This urban hotel, is located in Paradise Street and Hanover Street. It is in the centre of Liverpool. Close to the establishment clients can find Matthew Street and Cavern club. It is close to the Lime Street Station. It is 2 minutes away from the Liverpool One Shopping Centre, where you can find restaurants, bars and shops. It is 10 kilometres away from John Lennon Airport. \n\nROOM: The rooms are modern and comfortable, have ensuite bathrooms with bath or shower, a sofa-bed, a large workspace, an LCD television, films available at an additional cost, internet, a hairdryer, an ironing set, computer safe, a minibar, a coffee maker, a kettle, an individual air-conditioning system and a central heating system. \n\nFACILITIES: Guests have at their disposal a sauna, hydromassage, tanning salon, a gym and a covered heated swimming pool. Some services for an additional fee. \n\nOTHERS: Regarding gastronomy, the establishment offers a buffet breakfast. It has the Elements with A Breakfast, Lunch And Dinner Service<\/with_breakfast_lunch_dinner_service> Restaurant. \n\nPAYMENT METHODS: Accepted payment methods are credit cards, American Express, Diners Club, Mastercard, Visa and debit cards.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/68\/68152_8.jpg","latitudine":"53.4029200","longitudine":"-2.9844403","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"0.77","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"},{"id":"67575","provider_name":"veturis","provider":"veturis","session":"","name":"Hope Street Hotel","rating":4,"nation":"97","city":"394","nation_name":"","city_name":"","area_name":"","area_code":"","address":"40 HOPE STREET ","description":"HOTEL:\nBuilt around 1860 in the style of a Venetian palazo - a fashionable look of the day. Reinvented and renovated in 2003 into 48 simple, stylish, contemporary and comfortable rooms with a restaurant. Privately owned and independently run with an emphasis on friendliness, good food and thoughtful service.\n\nSITUACI\u00d3N:\nSitting pretty between two magnificent cathedrals, surrounded by two famous theatres, two legendary pubs, one treasured concert hall, and an abundance and variety of restaurants. Further afield they are a five minute walk into town and a 20 min drive to Liverpool John Lennon Airport.\n\nHABITACI\u00d3N:\n48 individually designed rooms, solid wood floors warmed by under floor heating and king sized beds draped in Egyptian cotton. Rain dance showerheads the size of dinner plates and Vola fittings complement timeless bathrooms that also include huge soft towels, mist free mirrors and REN products. Wall mounted LCD wide screen TVs, DVD and CD players and Arne Jacobsen telephones, along with complimentary broadband access in every room.\n\nCOMO LLEGAR:\nBy Car: From Liverpool John Lennon Airport - Depart. At the roundabout, take the first exit. At the roundabout, take the first exit onto Speke Hall Avenue. At the roundabout, take the second exit onto Speke Hall Avenue. Turn left onto Speke Road A561. the roundabout, take the first exit onto Speke Road A561. Continue onto A561. Turn left onto Dingle Lane A561. Turn right onto Park Road A561. Continue onto A561. Bear right onto Great George Street A5038. Bear right onto Berry Street A5038. Turn right onto Leece Street A5039. Continue onto A5039. Turn right onto Pilgrim Street. Turn left onto Back Hope Place. Arrive.\n\nMETODOS DE PAGO:\nVisa, American Express, MasterCard, Maestro and cash are accepted as methods of payment.\n\nOTRAS:\nThe London Carriage Works: modern international food, complemented by the use of local, organic and fresh seasonal produce. One of Liverpools leading restaurants, enjoying rave reviews and critical acclaim. It was voted one of the top ten restaurants outside London in the 2005 Hardens Guide and achieved Liverpools highest score for cooking in The Good Food Guide 2006. Most recently it won Taste of Englands Northwest 2008.","photo":"http:\/\/hoteles.veturis.com\/photos\/67\/67575_1.jpg","latitudine":"53.4008340","longitudine":"-2.9710220","max_age_infant":"0","max_age_child":"12","status":"","currency":"EUR","order":"10000000","distance":"1.60","markup_agency":"15","type":"hotel"}],"room":[],"amenities":[]}
```

Ok, in javascript I have to do this in success callback:

```
var data_hotel = data.hotel;
var string_hotel = JSON.stringify(data_hotel)
```

return me this error on stringify line:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 9574 of the JSON data
```

But If I copy the response from firebug tab HTML (not the response tab) in this way:

```
var data_response = '{"hotel":[{"id":"17911","provider_name":"ve....}]} '; // I can't copy because is too long for a stackoverflow question
var data_hotel = data_response.hotel;
var string_hotel = JSON.stringify(data_hotel)
```

This works fine and doesn't return errors.
Why??

Comment: This doesn't make any more sense now than it did a half hour ago. You cannot get a `JSON.parse()` exception from calling `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Are you trying to parse code that is already an object?

Comment: ... and that JSON is not valid.

Comment: same error with JSON.parse as a wrote a half hour ago @Pointy

Comment: I repeat: it is **impossible** to get a `JSON.parse()` exception from a call to `JSON.stringify()`. Therefore, that is not what's happening. The problem is clearly that your JSON is not valid, and therefore cannot be parsed.

Comment: the json is valid, not the long first but the second in one line, I have tried, but are the same

Comment: Ok so why the one line json is valid and the longest no? Why is not valid? this is the problem I think not parse or stringify @Pointy

Comment: The JSON that is posted in the question is not valid.

Comment: Ok, the first not but the second yes, but are from the same response, I really don't understand why, Have you tried with the second? the came from the same request and response, the first from the tab response and the second from the tab html of the response @Pointy

Comment: The reason the JSON in the response tab is not valid is because you're also copying the newlines added by Firebug. If you right click on the response and say "Copy Response Body" instead, it will be valid.

Comment: perfect so the json is valid, but why return error if I use stringify with the response, and if I copy the response inside a var it works fine? @Stryner

Comment: Please show the full code of your `$.ajax` call. The one you showed has nothing in the `success` callback. I did run your JSON through http://jsonlint.com/ and it checked out OK after fixing a couple errant carriage returns in the middle of strings.

Comment: We can't see your whole AJAX code. Please create a jsfiddle. You can tell it to return that data using the echo API

Comment: the full code is too long but the three first lines are what I have posted @nothingisnecessary

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri please console log `typeof data` as it's unclear whether you are actually getting back a string or an object.

Comment: return an object @Popnoodles

Comment: Did you console log to get that or are you assuming?

Comment: Problem can't be reproduced http://jsfiddle.net/yt06z4mx/

Comment: it's difficult to reproduce the call because it call an external server mapped with IP that returns some private data

Comment: If you've got more data than shown above, check you don't have any double quotes inside your text strings.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that when you call

```
var data_hotel = data_response.hotel;
```

You're already pointing to the hotel element, meaning you should stringify

```
var string_hotel = JSON.stringify(data_hotel)
```

and not

```
var string_hotel = JSON.stringify(data_hotel.hotel)
```

Comment: No isn't this the problem sorry

Comment: @Underfrog OP has since edited that error out of the question

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri is seems it was part of the problem if you edited the code to include my answer. Is the error now exactly the same one? That would be surprising.